# How to create multiple checkbox selection in a metabox?

Tags: wordpress

I have a loop that generates multiple checkbox in a wordpress metabox

```
<?php
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'agenti', 'posts_per_page' => 1000, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            $agente = get_the_title();
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="agente" value="agente"> '.$agente.'</br>';
            endwhile;
        ?>
```

Then

```
$mydata_agente = $_POST['agente'];
```

and

```
update_post_meta($post_id, "agente", $mydata_agente);
```

It's obviously not corrected because i probably need to save the selections in a array.

How can I save the selection?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a value that is checked as object. If you want to set as checked, into a value you need to put `checked="checked"` for example:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="agente" value="agente"> '.$agente.'</br>';
        endwhile;
```

Comment: I actually only need to save the items that are checked